# gsa double encoding partialfields

Tags: urlencode, google-search-appliance

I'm trying to build a correct query string for the GSA with partialfiels that contains the filters selected by users. 
Looking at the [google documentation](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/gsa_doc_set/xml_reference/appendices.html#1081896) I have to double encode values.
I write this simple function but if I select a filter that contains special chars (example: foo's pen) it doesn't work and GSA returns me 0 results.

```
protected function myUrlEncode($str) {
    $str = rawurlencode($str);
    $replacements = array('%2D', '%2E', '%7E');
    $entities = array('-','.','~');
    $str = str_replace($entities, $replacements, $str);
    return urlencode($str);
}
```

this function returns foo%2527s%2520pen that I use in the url: 
&partialfields=metaname:foo%2527s%2520pen

Comment: can you provide yours solution?

Comment: I add the answer to the post.. hope is what you're looking for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the probelm is due to special character in your metadata content/value.
Since you are using partialfields request parameter, try to hit GSA with partialfields=metaname:foo (encode it before firing the query).
This should resolve your issue.

I had similar issue long back then I modified content sources to remove special characters from metadata name and content.

Hope it helps.

Regards,

Mohan

Answer (score 1):

for each filter to send to the gsa I use this format:

```
$inmeta[] = urlencode("<filter_name>=".$this->myUrlEncode(<filter_value>));
```

then I simply concatenate them as follows:

```
if(sizeof($inmeta)) {
                foreach($inmeta as $val) {
                    $inmeta_str .= "+inmeta:".$val;
                }
            }
```

with this myUrlEncode():

```
protected function myUrlEncode($str) {
        $str = str_replace('%', '%25', $str);
        $replacements = array('%20', '%2D', '%2E', '%7E', '%21', '%2A', '%27', '%28', '%29', '%3B', '%3A', '%40', '%26', '%3D', '%2B', '%24', '%2C', '%2F', '%3F', '%23', '%5B', '%5D');
        $entities = array(' ', '-','.','~', '!', '*', "'", "(", ")", ";", ":", "@", "&", "=", "+", "$", ",", "/", "?", "#", "[", "]");
        return str_replace($entities, $replacements, $str);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not good at php, as i can see you have the same result foo%2527s%2520pen??

Comment: sorry.. I dont remember exactly what was my solution, but I think that I solved using inmeta instead of partialfields.. 
Try to look at the url created by the GSA in the default front end when you use the filters.. you should see what's the problem with your query